# SET user defined variable in mysql return null?

Tags: mysql

When I created a  user defined variable using

```
SET @a =10;
```

also i checked

```
SET @a := 10;
```

the above query executed successfully. while accessing the variable it gives me `NULL` value instead of `10`. I accessed the defined variables  using this query

```
SELECT @a;
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Which version of MySQL are you using? Where are you executing the queries?

Comment: Using the latter syntax: SET @a := 10; it just works for me. Variables are tied to a tcp connection, are you trying everything during the same session?

Comment: You should set and access user variable in the same session. ...SET @a=10 and SET @a:=10 are equal.

Comment: the version i use is MySQL 5.1.49-1ubuntu8.1,i am executing this in mysql query browser

Comment: i don't get the meaning for same session,, you mean that executing all at same time..

Comment: Not at the same time, but in the same session (mysql connection). Some tools may open another connection. Try to run those statements as a script or run in the MySQL Command-Line Tool - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html

Comment: @Devart yes,it works fine in command line tool,still i know not what exactly the issue working with query browser in ubuntu platform.

Comment: Try to run 'SELECT CONNECTION_ID();' query after 'SET @a= 10;' and after 'SELECT @a;' to check that session it the same.

Comment: @Devart ,yes it gives me the CONNECTION_ID AS 1,,,i try this in windows platform,, it works fine anyway thanks for your valuable comments ,,i have to put some research on this,,and let you know update by tomorrow,,thanks man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way this can happen (in a client session) - and the way it happens for me from time to time - is you get bit by a short timeout on the client connection. It goes like this:

```
mysql> set @a = 10;

mysql> [wait for N+1 minutes, where N is the client timeout]

mysql> select @a;
+------+
| NULL |
+------+
| NULL | 
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

You have to initialize your variables and use them within a contiguous client session. When the session goes away, you lose all your variables.

The other explanation, as pointed out by others in the comments, is that the commands are hitting the server from different connections; your problem might not be a timeout, but that you are originating the "SET ..." and "SELECT ..." commands in different connections. User variables are not shared across different connections.