# SQLYog set variables for MySQL returns null

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin, sqlyog

Referencing:
[SET user defined variable in mysql return null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9159779/set-user-defined-variable-in-mysql-return-null)

I tested the following code:

```
SET @rank=0;
SELECT *, @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank FROM points
```

For *points* in PhpMyAdmin it returns:

```
id | user_id | points | rank
-----------------------------
2  | 133845  | 220    | 1
4  | 134084  | 220    | 2
5  |      1  | 150    | 3
7  | 134086  | 145    | 4
```

HOWEVER in SQLYog all the ranks return as "***NULL***" I checked my configs and set timeout to 28800 seconds and turned off compression protocol. MySQL seems to stay on one single session but SQLYog seems to be using two connections for this query. How can I set the application to one single connection so I don't lose the variable values?

Comment: did you use the "Execute all statements" command?
I tried it here and it works fine. Also you can create a post at forums.webyog.com for further assistance.

Comment: I get the same buggy behaviour on SQLyog (v11). Here is how to reproduce it:
<code>SET \@year := 2014;
SELECT \@year as Year;</code>
The Year will return NULL.

Comment: About my comment above - just remove the "\" sign from "\@year".

Comment: Seems like it has to do with the pattern of setting the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple queries within one instance. They're being stacked in individual instances.

As Jan suggest "Execute all statements" command should do the trick.